# JPA - load different implementations of abstract property

Tags: java, jpa, abstract

My Java EE project is running on WildFly 8 and is using JPA 2.1.
There is an Entity Person, an abstract Entity AbstractMatch and two entities, which implement AbstractMatch: FootballMatch and HockeyMatch.

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @Email
  @NotNull
  private String email;

  @ManyToMany(targetEntity=FootballMatch.class)
  private List<AbstractMatch> matches
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractMatch implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  protected Long id;
}

@Entity
public class FootballMatch extends AbstractMatchEntity {
}
```

Person has an ManyToMany relationship to AbstractMatch. The targetEntity attribute of the ManyToMany annotation defines the class type to load. So if I load a Person from the database, all matches will be casted to this class type (in this example to FootballMatch). How to load the original class type, which the object had when it was persisted?

Comment: You can avoid using `targetEntity` by using generics in your collection of `IMatch`. Also: `IMatch` sounds like an interface, but shouldn't it be an abstract class which enables inheritance in JPA?

Comment: I was talking about an abstract class, using @MappedSuperclass annotation. I updated the question for better explanation. My question is not about defining the database tables, it's about the loading phase. I want to load a Person from database and all the abstractMatch-objects (property matches) shall have the class type it had while they got persisted.

Comment: Well, that's one of the powerful features of JPA. You needn't worry about it. Just model your `@ManyToMany` relation without the `targetEntity`. The generic type information `AbstractMatch` will suffice. For referential integrity I suggest to not use `TABLE_PER_CLASS` as inheritance strategy in conjunction with an `@ManyToMany` relation, because this makes it impossible to have an n:m table with just one foreign key to your `AbstractMatch`entities.

Comment: I thought that 'targetEntity' is necessary because if I did not specifiy it, an exception was thrown. After your answer I tried it again and it worked. So thanks :)